# How do I import a .zip minecraft map into Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I use Minecraft Education Edition. I have downloaded a few custom maps online (.zip) but whenever I try to import the extracted files into Minecraft, they don't show up.

What exactly do I need to do to be able to get them available within the game?

Comment: Like QC Scooter sorta touches on, chances are that if it is a `.zip` it is for java edition and will not work

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to make sure that this .zip file isn’t a Minecraft Java world. This is because Education Edition runs on Minecraft Bedrock 1.14. If you’re sure it isn’t a Java world, just rename the file extension (the .zip) to “.mcworld”. Be sure not to install a map from 1.16+ or else it won’t work due to it coming from a later version.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to add a `.zip` file into education edition. You can only import `.mcworld`, `.mcpack`, and `.mcaddon` to your world.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the zip and drop it into the worlds folder. On bedrock edition it is com.mojang (C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_somestuffhere\LocalState\games\com.mojang). It should be in packages and should be something similar to that for education edition.

Or, you can rename it to an .mcworld and double click it (or, if you own Minecraft bedrock editon and education editon, right click it and open with Minecraft education edition). When renaming, you will get a warning which means you have done it right.